# Boot fail on zynq ultrascale+ mpsoc zu3eg on the ULTRA 96

Tags: boot, xilinx, zynq, petalinux

I followed this tutorial to boot the ULTRA 96 :

https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841783/Building+Xen+Hypervisor+with+Petalinux+2018.1

I'm using petalinux-v2018.2-final and xilinx-ultra96-reva-v2018.2-final.bsp

I built the project myself then copied necessary files into the SD card (BOOT.bin,xen.ub.system.dtb,image,rootfs.cpio.gz.u-boot) int the boot partition and the rootfs files(extracted from rootfs.cpio) into the root partition of the SD card. I even tried copying the same files from the pre-built images in the project but there is no response at all from the card when I enter sudo screen ... or even when I tried with trace32.

please help I'm stuck here and thank you for your time!

Update:
when I copied the prebuilt images and connected the board to a screen via display port, the system boots and opens a Linux kernel based system but when i searched if it's a Dom 0 for the xen i didn"t find anything( when I entered dmesg | grep xen it showed nothing). My problem is if this system is the Dom 0 for xen or it's simply a linux image on my board and thank you :)